# Wordpress permalink change to postname causing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am new to Wordpress and just built a website. Now when I changed the permalink to "postname", all the post and category pages are throwing  Internal error (screenshot at the bottom).

wordpress is NOT installed at root but in a directory named wp/ inside the root. I have tried all suggestions found on the internet like reinstalling plugins, deleting .htaccess file and regenerating through wordpress. But none worked. May be I am missing something. Here is the .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Error screenshot for post pages below:

[image]

Comment: I'll assume mysite.com is replaced with your domain already. But besides that you have /my_subdir/$1 change it to /wp/$1. You can also get further details if you look at the php error log. Do you have access to it?

Comment: @OrlandoP. Yes, mysite.com is replaced with my domain. I replaced /my_subdir/$1 to /wp/$1. Now it is returning a 404 page not found for all the post and category pages. So, surely issue is with the .htaccess file. Not sure what a is missing.

Comment: try to refresh your permalinks. Go to your settings and change the permalink structure, then change it back.